# NumericTextBox has incorrect currency symbol

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

I can't get the correct currency symbol to appear in my numeric textbox, even though the locale is set correctly.

I know it's set correctly because this:

```
mounted() {
    var culture = kendo.culture();
    console.log(culture.name);
}
```

results in this:

> en-GB

My component is defined as follows:

```
<numeric-textbox :placeholder="'£0.00'" :min="0" :format="'c2'" :v-model="amountValue"
                 :disabled="amountDisabled" />
```

but as soon as a number is entered (e.g. 100) it shows the wrong currency symbol, i.e.:

```
$100.00
```

I'm clearly missing something; is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about `vue.js` but in `jQuery`, I handle it like this:

```
format: "€0"
...
format: "€0.0"
...
format: "€0.00"
```

Example: [Kendo currency format](https://dojo.telerik.com/uVeRibIv)

Comment: That doesn't work for me. It makes the field contents un-editable. I think I'll give up and use a plain text field.